# Fetching JSON data square brackets

Tags: php, json

I'm wondering how to fetch JSON data from a JSON file that contains square brackets. I have a JSON code like this:

```
"events": [
    {
        "id": 462467,
        "eventDetails": [
            70,
            1,
            [
                "Swansea City - Manchester City",
                "Swansea City - Manchester City",
                "Swansea-ManCity"
            ],
```

I'm using foreach statements to get the values for "eventDetails", but how can i sort out the number "1", and also fetch each team name separately?
The php statement I am trying to perform is: If the second value is "1", then fetch team names.

This is what I have so far:

```
 foreach($array2['events'] as $key=>$val)

    {     
         foreach($val['eventDetails'] as $values)
         {

            if ($values['70,1']) { echo "test"; }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Just use json_decode() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In json brackets mean stdClass (object) ,so:

```
foreach($array2->events as $key=>$val){    
    echo($val->eventDetails[0]);//70
    echo($val->eventDetails[1]);//1
    foreach($val->eventDetails[2] as $team)
         echo $team;
}
```

Comment: the "echo $team" is outputting all three team data `Swansea City - Manchester CitySwansea City - Manchester CitySwansea-ManCity`. How tofetch one value for Swansea and one value for ManCity?

Comment: Use array_unique() function to remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `file_get_contents()` like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents( $filename );
$json = json_decode( $content );
print_r( $json );
```

More information here:

https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

And here:

https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: How may I use json_decode to fetch for example the team names separately? json_decode returns `Array ( [0] => Swansea City - Manchester City [1] => Swansea City - Manchester City [2] => Swansea-ManCity )`.